# Suppose $X_t$ is a brownian motion with $X_0 \sim u_0$. What is the probability density of $X_t$? (heat equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, heat-equation

> Suppose $u_0(x) = 2x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $u_0(x)=0$ otherwise. Suppose $X_t$ is a brownian motion with $X_0 \sim u_0$. What is the probability density of $X_t$?

Since $X_t$ is a brownian motion, the density should satisfy the heat equation
$$ \partial_t u = \frac{1}{2} \partial_x^2 u .$$
The first part of the question gives us initial conditions for the heat equation $u_0(x) = 2x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $u_0(x)=0$ otherwise.

I think the problem boils down to solving the heat equation for this initial condition. How would this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $(B_t^x)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion started at $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, then the density of $B_t^x$ is given by

$$p_t^x(y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{d/2}} \exp \left(- \frac{|y-x|^2}{2t} \right).$$

Using the Dirac measure we can rewrite this as follows:

$$p_t^x(y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{d/2}} \int \exp \left(- \frac{|y-z|^2}{2t} \right) \delta_x(dz) $$

Note that $\delta_x$ is the initial distribution of the Brownian motion $(B_t^x)_{t \geq 0}$. If we replace $\delta_x$ by some general distribution, say $\mu$, we get

$$p_t^{\mu}(y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{d/2}} \int \exp \left(- \frac{|y-z|^2}{2t} \right) \, \mu(dz).$$

Roughly this means that we mix the densities $(p_t^x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}$ according to our given initial distribution. In particular, if $\mu(dz) = u_0(z) \, dz$ for some density $u_0$, we have

$$p_t^{\mu}(y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{d/2}} \int \exp \left(- \frac{|y-z|^2}{2t} \right) u_0(z) \, dz.$$

A straight-forward calculation shows that this function does indeed satisfy the heat equation. Moreover, one can show that $p_t^{\mu}(y) \to u_0(y)$ as $t \to 0$. Note that the density $(p_t^{\mu})$ is the convolution of the initial distribution and the heat kernel.

This is the probabilistic approach. The more popular approach to solve the heat equation uses Fourier methods (i.e. take the Fourier transform of the heat equation, do some calculations and then invert the Fourier transform to get the solution $u$). You will find this in (almost) any book on PDEs.

Comment: I know what the dirac delta function is but how does one interpret the notation $\delta_x(dz)$ in the integrand? And can you explain further what you mean by "mix the densities $(p_t^x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}$"?

Comment: @mathjacks There is no such thing as a dirac delta function. $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure; it satisfies $$\delta_x(B) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \notin B, \\ 1, & x \in B \end{cases}$$ for any set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$. Since you are asking about Brownian motion, I assumed that you are (at least a bit) familiar with measure theory. Concerning mixing: As I said $p_t^x$ is the density of a Brownian motion with inital distribution $\mu = \delta_x$. In order to construct Brownian motions with more general distributions, we mix/superpose the processes $(B_t^x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}$.

Comment: E.g. if we would like to have a Brownian motion with initial distribution $\mu = \frac{1}{2} \delta_{-1}+ \frac{1}{2} \delta_{1}$ (i.e. it starts with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ at $1$ and $-1$, respectively), we would expect that a superposition of the processes $B_t^1$ and $B_t^{-1}$ does the job, i.e. $$B_t^{\mu} := \frac{1}{2} B_t^1 + \frac{1}{2} B_t^{-1}.$$ We can rewrite this as $$B_t^{\mu} = \int B_t^x \, \mu(dx).$$ This, however, does not only work for discrete distributions $mu$, but actually for any distribution $\mu$. The corresponding density $p_t^{\mu}$ of $(B_t^{\mu})_t$ is [...]

Comment: given by the formula I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This makes sense to me now. The probabilistic approach is helpful to see and much more informative than just solving the heat equation using standard techniques from PDE.

Comment: I notice your answer also looks like a convolution. I have another idea where if we write $B_t = B_0 + (B_t - B_0)$ where $B_0 \sim u_0$, we can use the independent increments property and the fact that the distribution of the sum of independent random variables is equal to the convolution of their densities. This gives us another probabilistic approach, though yours is much more general/flexible.

Comment: @mathjacks Yeah, that's true. (I did mention that it is a convolution, didn't I? ;) )